# RCP Toolbar items order change in e4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, toolbar

I am trying to update a RCP Eclipse 3 application to Eclipse 4.5 target platform. There are some differences depending on the compatibility layer. 
One difference is the order of items in the toolbar in the main menu.

Old version:
[image]

New version:
[image]

The red marked icons are added with an `ActionBarAdvisor`, the other icons are added in the plugin.xml as toolbar commands. 
Why does the order change? Do I need to add the toolbar items programmatically?

**UPDATE:**

If I use the option -clearPersistedState the toolbar are ordered like the in the old version. Removing the flag again creates the toolbar shown in the new version screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution after some digging in various issues in the Eclipse Bugtracker.

In the method `fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar)` add the toolbar items to an instance of `ToolbarManager` and then add it as ToolBarContributionItem with ID `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar`

to the coolbar:

```
@Override
protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar)
{
    IToolBarManager manager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
    manager.add(action1);
    ...

    coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(manager, "toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar"));
}
```

In the plugin.xml add the toolbars to a menuContribution with the same ID `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar`. This causes the other toolbars to be added after the coolbar.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. When workspace is just created, toolbar is in the right order, on the next launch my button added by `ActionBarAdvisor` are on the right.

Your option `-clearPersistedState` worked for me. I'm interested to know the origin of this problem if anyone has the information

Comment: this should be a comment.